# SignalR performance

Tags: signalr, high-load

We have a web-based game (SignalR for communication), our workload will be:

- 5,000 - 20,000 concurrent client with 0.5 - 2 messages/client/second ~= 10-40k messages/secs

with the following server is there any problem handle the load (assume that signalr has 80-90% cpu) ?

- dual hex-cores L5639 (2.13Ghz)
- 24G Ram
- windows server 2012 standard

(with long-polling we can easily do that @ 5-10% cpu)

Comment: any news on how SignalR performed ?

Comment: SignalR has too much features so we wrote a custom web-socket-library,  200k messages/sec : )

Comment: Any significant modifications to achieve your performance? Is your library open source by chance?

Answer (score 13):

As much as I dont want to write it, "it depends" is very much accurate here. SignalR can scale way beyond your requirements. Damnie Edwards (co-creator of SignalR) has got 150k connections from a single 10GB server though:

https://twitter.com/DamianEdwards/status/486642486350061568